# Best way to mount a phone in the car

Tags: car, phone, cell-phone

I have a Toyota Matrix and want to mount my iPhone 7 ( or future versions) for easy access to directions, etc. while still being able to charge it. Right now it sits in the cup holder or I stuff it behind the strap on the sun visor, neither of which is ideal. The Matrix doesn't have many great mounting spots where I could clip something to the dash, and I'd rather not block any of my vents. Any suggestions?

Comment: I do not think this needs a lifehack solution. There are many commercially available phone holders, many of them come with a sucker that will attach to the window or the dash and hold all kinds of phones safely.

Comment: Not a suggestion or endorsement for any particular product, but a quick google search turned up this to show that such products are available and easy to find: https://www.staples.ca/en/Dash-Crab-Smartphone-Car-Mount/product_721522_2-CA_1_20001

Comment: A lot of phone holders are available in the market, please do Google them and find out that suits you

Comment: @Willeke I honestly would love to see a good lifehack to this question, I do. At least there are two ideas below that go beyond the obvious 'commercially available phone holder', but the number of those other suggestions goes imo out of hand and drown the more original suggestions. I'm honestly not sure how to improve/fix that. I've flagged the question to get a newbie lock put on, but is that going to be enough?

Comment: @Flint  Many interesting (if not pure lifehack) questions are closed, answers deleted and the questions hidden or wiped (can not see what, not having enough rep.) This one was marked 'not needing life hack solution before the answers were given and was left open, not even protected so all new guys can add their favorite internet bought solution.

Comment: @Willeke Actually I agree that this question was not closed and left open initially. But I think it needs a lock now. And editing. I don't have the rep either to do most of these things and with the edits I can do (suggest) I would just create a bigger mess and probably offend people.

Comment: I feel there is more to discuss, [so I've started something](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19330/conversation/flints-phone-holder-blurb) on [chat].

Answer (score 4):

As I have already commented, a simple google search will provide you enough results, anyway, I am adding up a bit for you.

The following is most suited for you, as it neither does any harm to your dashboard nor it does any harm to your vents.
[image]

The best position for fixing would be the one as shown below
[image]

Even you can find certain models that are designed to fit your car, by searching for: "Dashboard Phone Mount Holder"

Answer (score 4):

I use a magnet, like this:

[image: pumkin]
It costs [**10.99€**](https://www.amazon.de/PUMPKIN-Handyhalter-Handyhalterung-Autohalterung-Einstellbar/dp/B00Y81PKYI)

***Pros***:

- **Easy** to install
- **flexible** 360 Degrees
- **simple** attaching

***Cons***:

- **price**
- **fix** on phone or case

## A cheap alternative for tinkerer

You could simply stripe a rubberband through your cooling system like this:

[image: Rubberband lifehack]

This would be an ultimate lifehack.

Comment: That answer has already been given.

Comment: yes, see my answer

Comment: This seems to be a product, not a hack.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick you're right, so I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

I found a magnetic holder - it fits to the air vent (but you can also get windshield mounts) and I can see it easily. 
It comes with a small adhesive magnet that I mount invisibly inside my phone's protective shell.  Its much smaller than the first solution shown above. You can pivot it to your preference.

[magnetic phone holder example](https://www.gearbest.com/car-phone-holder/pp_626136.html?currency=GBP&vip=2422326&gclid=CjwKCAjw0qLOBRBUEiwAMG5xMLzvAJ5ruKLRaIVmuyjAXDsEhoT-UsHzWzutulNkRYxzXltmEzmrMBoCWJYQAvD_BwE)

Answer (score 1):

I find heavy, non-slip holders to be the best. Rather than using suction cups or clips, they use their weight and a non-slip coating to stay in place. They are easy to position on the dashboard and easy to remove.

I find suction cups always come away eventually. The constant heating/cooling cycles inside cars probably don't help. Clips cover your vents.

Magnetic mounts work well for holding the phone, but be aware that they affect the accelerometer and compass. GPS is usually fine but you may find your phone doesn't detect the direction it is facing quite as well as it otherwise would.

Another excellent option is to avoid mounting the phone at all and get a head unit that supports Carplay (or Android Auto for Android devices, or just plain MirrorLink). This will allow you to plug the phone in and keep it out of the way, with the app displayed on the car's infotainment screen.

Comment: This is super helpful, thanks! Except my car is older and doesn't have any kind of screen.

Comment: If it has an old style head unit you might be able to upgrade it fairly easily.

Comment: That's probably true but is well outside the range of what I'm interested in doing :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Nato Mount]

Get a nato mount.  A few of us in my Jeep club have them and they survive some pretty extreme trail runs and rock climbing.  The magnet is super strong.

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks, IdahoFish and thanks for your answer. Just some feedback. This site is about [life-hacks, uncommon solutions to common problems](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2431/a-lifehacks-manifesto). We welcome posts that introduce new ways to solve a problem and there were already two posts that recommended the concept of magnetic phone holders. So the new thing from your post is, that you are recommending another make of a magnetic phone holder. Comparing products is not what this site is about though.